# Get the date of last purchase of product, by customer

Tags: magento2, product, customer

How can I get the last date that a customer has purchased a product?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get customer's last order and then any order info:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder;

public function __construct(
    OrderRepository $orderRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
}

/**
 * @param int $customerId
 * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
 */
public function getCustomerOrders(int $customerId): OrderSearchResultInterface
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(OrderInterface::CUSTOMER_ID, $customerId);
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(OrderInterface::STATUS, ['canceled', 'holded'], 'nin');
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $searchCriteria->setSortOrders(
        [
            $this->sortOrderBuilder
                ->setField(OrderInterface::CREATED_AT)
                ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC)
                ->create()
        ]
    );
    $searchResults = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    return $searchResults;
}

public function getLastOrder()
{
    $result = null;
    $searchResults = $this->getCustomerOrders(<customer_id_here>);

    if ($searchResults->getTotalCount() > 0) {
        $orders = $searchResults->getList();
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $lastOrder */
        $lastOrder = reset($orders);
        $result = $lastOrder;
    }
    return $result;
}
```